# (bug) Closing a question that should be on another .SE site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I voted to close [this question on programming](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12854/in-c-programing-a-single-variable-cannot-take-a-character-to-it-continuously), and wanted to vote to send it to StackOverflow, but noticed that I couldn't choose to do that:

[image]

[image: Second Close window]

Notice that I cannot click "Vote to Close" on the second screen unless I select the meta site, which is not the appropriate site for this question. Is there a way to add either a list of .SE sites, or be able to type in a site, or at least leave it blank so it can reflect that it should be on another site?

Answer (score 4):

That question would have gotten closed on Stack Overflow.

It is a *bad* question - OP is asking people to do his work for him and would have gotten shot down rather quickly.

---

That is orthogonal to your question though - there are up to 5 slots for migration on every Stack Exchange site - sites still in beta only have a migration path to their child-meta (for obvious reasons), but no others.

Why is that?

Because it is not clear when a site starts what the best 4 other options should be - this takes time to find out as off-topic questions accumulate and people want to migrate them.

Now, for this site, I doubt that Stack Overflow should take one of these slots - how often would programming come up here? Not often, I suspect.

It is better to use these slots for sites that will actually make a good migration path - for topics that come up fairly often here but are not in the site scope but are in another site scope.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution is to leave the proposed migration site as a comment, and allow the mods to do the migration (we can always do this, regardless of status).